# How can I query average document size on a site?

Tags: document-library

I am doing capacity planning for a new SharePoint 2010 site, and it would be useful to know the average file size on an existing SharePoint 2007 Server we have for comparision.

Does anyone know if there is a way to query this?

Added bonus would be querying the average number of files per user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could take quite a long time to run, but here's the straight forward method:

```
$count = 0L
$totalSize = 0L
$WebApplications = Get-SPWebApplication
foreach ($webApp in $WebApplications){
  foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites){
    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs){
      foreach ($list in $web.Lists){
        if ($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"){
          foreach ($item in $list.Items){
            $totalSize += $item.File.Length
            $count++
          }
        }
      }
      $web.Dispose()
    }
    $site.Dispose()
  }
}
Write-Host "Average file size: $($totalSize/$count)"
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! It is just a one off sizing exercise, so speed doesn't really matter.